# Can someone please explain this college exercise

Tags: c++, pointers

Today i have learned about pointers  and i have this:

```
char message[]="hello everyone";
char *pm;
pm=message;
cout<<&pm[0];
```

This would output `hello everyone`, I want to know why? because & should output the address of pm[0] not the hole value. Can someone explain?

Comment: `&pm[0]` is the same as `pm`, which is the same as `message`. If you `cout << message` you would get `hello everyone` and yet you aren't surprised by it.
The answer is that operator << is overloaded to print the whole character array if it takes a pointer to a const char.

Comment: @NoelPerezGonzalez `pm` is not the same as `message`. `message` is an array whereas `pm` is a pointer.

Comment: @rightføld true, I meant pm contains the same info as message, that is, the address of the first element of the array.

Comment: @NoelPerezGonzalez: Please do not spread the horrible myth and rumour that arrays and pointers are the same thing; `message` and `pm` are _absolutely_ not the same thing. Your example about `cout << message` has more to do with array name decay and less to do with some imaginary "arrays are pointers" nonsense.

Comment: pm[0] represent the char value at index 0. &pm[0] represent its address. So here &pm[0] == pm == message. If we pass char* to the << operator, it output null terminated string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message` is an array of `char`s containing `hello everyone\0`.

When you do `pm = message;`, the array `message` undergoes array-to-pointer conversion, which gives you a pointer pointing at the first element in the array. So `pm` now points at the very first `char` in the array (the `h` character).

`pm[0]` is equivalent to `*(pm + 0)`, which basically just gives you the first character in the array. Then `&pm[0]` is taking the address of that character, giving you a pointer to the first character. So `pm` and `&pm[0]` are exactly the same.

`cout` has a special overload for handling `char*`s. When you pass a `char*` to `cout`, it assumes that you want it to print it out like a C-style string, where the `char*` is pointing at the first character in an array of characters that end with `\0`.

Answer (score 4):

`&pm[0]` is of type `char*`. `<<` is overloaded for `char const*` to print all characters until `'\0'`. If you want to print the address you have to convert it to `void*` first.

Comment: Can the downvoter elaborate? How does this not answer the question or how is it wrong or unhelpful?

Comment: Looks like somebody is on a down-voting spree.

Answer (score 1):

`&pm[0]` is the same as `&(*(pm+0))` which is the same as `&(*pm)` which is the same as `pm`. And `pm` points to the first element of the zero-terminated character array `message`.

Now, the `<<` operator for the output stream, when passed a `char*` or `const char*` treats that as a pointer to a null-terminated array of characters. That is, a C string.

So, the entire contents of the string are output to the output stream.

> `&` should output the address of `pm[0]`

No, the `&` operator is not related to the output. The `&` operator is part of the expression `&pm[0]`. This expression is evaluated, as described above. And the result of that evaluation is passed to the best matching overload of the output stream's `<<` operator. It is the `<<` operator that determines how the value of your expression is output, and that determination is based on the type of your expression.

In order to output an address, you would need to supply an argument of a different type, for instance `void*`. You can cast the `char*` pointer like this:

```
static_cast<const void*>(&pm[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually, giving a pointer to `std::cout` will result in the pointer's value (the memory address it contains) being printed.

However, there is a *special case* for `[const] char*`, which is automatically assumed to be a C-style string and therefore dereferenced to be treated like one. This (in concert with array name decay) is to allow you to do things like `std::cout << "Hello world\n";` without just getting a memory address instead.

Comment: no, you don't need an overload for `[const] char*` for string literals.

Comment: @Abyx: No but, regardless, that's what the Standard Library does (`[C++11: 27.7.3.6.4]` — happy reading).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the std lib doesn't do it *only* for *literals*.

Comment: @Abyx: I've never claimed that it does.